# Why is the following .sh script saying .py command not found when the script is in PATH?

Tags: python, bash, macos, bioinformatics

I am trying to run the Example Workflow in https://rki_bioinformatics.gitlab.io/ditasic/, in which example.sh is the major bash script that will take the example data and output some data matrices.

In the example.sh script which will run the example workflow, we have the following line 9:

```
ditasic_matrix.py -l 100 -o output/similarity_matrix35.npy data/reference_paths
```

However, when example.sh is run in the terminal of macOS, the following message arises:

```
DiTaSic /ditasic_example/example.sh: line 9: ditasic_matrix.py: command not found
```

But ditasic_matrix.py already exists in the path I have set for the terminal. I have put ditasic_matrix.py in a directory whose path I have added to the PATH of the terminal by

```
export PATH="$PATH":
```

So what has happened that leads to the command not found?

Comment: Is "ditasic_matrix.py" executable?

Comment: Is `export PATH="$PATH":`actually the command you used? You have to specify the directory to add

Comment: I would add a into example.sh just before line 9 a line "echo PATH=$PATH". Also, as thatotherguy suggested, `export PATH="$PATH":` does not make sense. There is no directory after the final colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ditasic_matrix.py` line in your script to be `./ditasic_matrix.py` because of current path not being included in executable search.

If it still doesn't execute, maybe the file does not have executable bit set.

Open a terminal/console in that folder and issue

```
chmod +x ditasic_matrix.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ditasic_matrix.py` file seems to have the following interpreter setting on it: `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Since you seem to not be able to run it, it seems that this is not your actual path to running Python. Please make sure that:

1) You have Python installed

2) You can execute Python programs by running `python` in the command line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I indeed have Python installed. And when I type python in command line I do have the ">>>" prompts.

Comment: @Ripol : This can't be the reason in **this** case, because the error message says _ditasic_matrix.py: command not found_, so either the directory of the Python file is not in the PATH, or the file is not executable.